# jQuery not registering click

Tags: jquery, dynamic

The problem I am having is that I can click my element to begin with and everything works accordingly, however after I press the S-key to change my element from a textarea->paragraph, I can no longer click and no clicks are registered.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#dynamic').click(function() {
        log('`Clicked`');
        var text = $('#dynamic').text();
        $('#dynamic').replaceWith('<textarea id="dynamic">' + text + '</textarea>');
    });

    $(document).keydown(function(e) {
        log(e.which);
        switch(e.which) {
            // S key
            case 83:
                if ($('#dynamic').is('textarea')) {
                    var text = $('#dynamic').val();
                    $('#dynamic').replaceWith('<p id="dynamic">' + text + '</p>');
                }
                break;
            default: return;
        }
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

This is the code I am using, and it registers the first click, but not the second after the element conversion. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The element that `$('#dynamic')` returned doesn't exist any more. You'll have to use event delegation to bind the event handler:

```
$(document).on('click', '#dynamic', function() {
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When you replace the original element it is *gone* - along with any handlers that were bound directly to it. You can rebind the handler again at the point where you recreate it, or you can using a delegated event handler, in which case you probably want to add a test as to whether the element is already a textarea:

```
$(document).on('click', '#dynamic', function() {
    if (this.tagName === "TEXTAREA") return; // already a textarea, so no action needed
    log('`Clicked`');
    var text = $('#dynamic').text();
    $('#dynamic').replaceWith('<textarea id="dynamic">' + text + '</textarea>');
});
```